# How to fix an error when using ko.TeX for typesetting Korean words?

Tags: pdftex, texworks

I have a problem using [ko.TeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/korean/kotex-utf) for writing Korean words. I use MikTeX 2.9 with TeXworks as editor and pdfLaTeX as engine. I haven't used ko.TeX package, yet, so when I write Korean words (e.g. 남) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kotex}
\begin{document}
 남
\end{document}
```

TeXworks will install missing package (1) [kotex-utf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/korean/kotex-utf) and then (2) [kotex-plain](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kotex-plain) during compilation but I'm getting this kind of error at the end:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \dhucs@serifhangulfont 
1.4 남
```

Are we able to solve this particular problem?

Comment: Do you really think people will be able to guess what's wrong on the basis of the information you've provided? Please help us to help you and add a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your example is compilable (TL2013, lualatex+xelatex), but I'm missing some fonts. It works for me (TL2013, pdflatex). This is working for me but I'm not using ko.TeX and therefore I'm not solving your question: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{batang.ttc}
\begin{document}
 남 abc
\end{document}`

Comment: The example compiles on TeX Live 2013; if I try with TeX Live 2012, the error `File `kotexutf.sty' not found` pops out. I can't test on MiKTeX, but my feeling is that you should do an update of all your packages.

Comment: I have reinstall MikTeX by using the latest version which covers all packages including kotex but the same error happens

Comment: @egreg I also install Tex Live 2013 but I have same errors. Is there any suggestion? maybe I miss something

Answer (score 1):

The `kotex-utf` package in MiKTeX omits a small file `hfontspec.default`.
You can use `cjk-ko` instead of `kotex-utf` with putting `[cjk]` option to `kotex`, `\usepackage[cjk]{kotex}`. Or make a 'hfontspec.default' file by yourself. Visit [KTUG (Korean TeX Users Group) wiki site](http://wiki.ktug.org/wiki/wiki.php/HangulAndMiKTeX?action=show&redirect=MiKTeX#s-2.2) (in Korean).

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out what the equivalent of `\setmainhangulfont` is for the cjk package, even after trying to read its manual. How do you keep using the same opentype font as with `kotex`, instead of whatever `cjk` wants to use?